# How to return all array items in array before a specific key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm needing to return items from an array. The difficulty is that arrays returned from a fetch request have the possibility of returning different keys that can't be determined prior to the return. The common denominator is the 'created_by' key. As the title suggests, I need to know a way that can render all the previous values, prior to the created_by key, dynamically.

This is the render/map method I have setup now that will not work as it stands.

```
return <div className="data-subContainer">
      {resData.map(item => <span key={item.id}>{item[1.3]} - <b>{item[2]}</b></span>)}
    </div>
```

resData Ouput:

```
    (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {4: "X", 5: "X", 6: "05/16/2020", id: "4627", form_id: "3", post_id: null, date_created: "2020-05-16 05:27:50", date_updated: "2020-05-16 05:27:50", …}
1: {4: "X", 5: "X", 6: "05/14/2020", id: "4618", form_id: "3", post_id: null, date_created: "2020-05-14 13:50:32", date_updated: "2020-05-14 13:50:32", …}
2: {4: "X", 5: "X", 6: "03/02/2020", id: "4124", form_id: "3", post_id: null, date_created: "2020-03-02 19:01:18", date_updated: "2020-03-02 19:01:18", …}
3: {4: "X", 5: "X", 6: "02/27/2020", id: "4103", form_id: "3", post_id: null, date_created: "2020-02-27 00:38:54", date_updated: "2020-02-27 00:38:54", …}
4: {4: "X", 5: "X", 6: "02/27/2020", id: "4102", form_id: "3", post_id: null, date_created: "2020-02-27 00:38:14", date_updated: "2020-02-27 00:38:14", …}
5: {4: "X", 5: "X", 6: "02/27/2020", id: "4101", form_id: "3", post_id: null, date_created: "2020-02-27 00:34:44", date_updated: "2020-02-27 00:34:44", …}
6: {4: "X", 5: "X", 6: "01/14/2020", id: "3853", form_id: "3", post_id: null, date_created: "2020-01-14 07:37:23", date_updated: "2020-01-14 07:37:23", …}
7: {4: "X", 5: "X", 6: "11/06/2019", id: "3503", form_id: "3", post_id: null, date_created: "2019-11-06 12:35:04", date_updated: "2019-11-06 12:35:04", …}
8: {4: "X", 5: "X", 6: "09/26/2019", id: "3283", form_id: "3", post_id: null, date_created: "2019-09-26 17:52:06", date_updated: "2019-09-26 17:52:06", …}
9: {4: "X", 5: "X", 6: "09/24/2019", id: "3263", form_id: "3", post_id: null, date_created: "2019-09-24 20:08:35", date_updated: "2019-09-24 20:08:35", …}
length: 10
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Example 1: (Notice key numbers are different than example 2)

```
1: "XX"
2: "XXXX"
3.2: ""
3.3: "XX"
3.4: ""
3.6: "X"
3.8: ""
4: "X"
5: "X"
8: "X"
10: "X"
11: "X"
12: "X"
13: "X"
created_by: "X"
```

Example 2:

```
1.2: ""
1.3: "X"
1.4: ""
1.6: "X"
1.8: ""
4: "X"
5: "X"
6: "X"
7: "X"
8: "X"
9: "X"
created_by: "X"
```

Comment: what should be the output of your examples given ?

Comment: What is the shape of data you retrieve?

Comment: @sçuçu I don't understand your question. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: What is resData? What is its structure? Is it an array like `[{1.3: "X"}, ...]`

Comment: Ah okay. I've edited the question to include the structure of resData (It's returned as an Object)

Comment: Actually that şs not correct. It is an array of those objects. So if I understand you have the mentioned key in those objetcs, and want to render the value of the props upto it in each object in the array. But there is a problem since JavaScript objects do not have a definite order same as you define them. I have explained this in my answer below.

Comment: Any progress on it?

Comment: @sçuçu sorry no. I've had to put that project on hold until next week at least. I will keep you updated of my progress though

Answer (score 0):

You can try to cast to Map

```
var resMap = new Map(Object.entries(resData));
```

Then you can normally iterate via keys

```
resMap.keys()
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

```
const resData = {
  1: 'XX',
  2: 'XXXX',
  3.2: '',
  3.3: 'XX',
  3.4: '',
  3.6: 'X',
  3.8: '',
  4: 'X',
  5: 'X',
  8: 'X',
  10: 'X',
  11: 'X',
  12: 'X',
  13: 'X',
  created_by: 'X',
  test: 1
};

const resMap = new Map(Object.entries(resData));
for (const [key, value] of resMap) {
  if (key === 'created_by') { return; }
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of how I would use this with my list of objects and get the values before created_by?

Comment: @SethSpivey Again, you cannot definitely get the properties in order in JavaScript objects. Better define the keys you want or unwant and go with these. I have explained in below answer that with an example.

Comment: You should specify it in original question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for in` to loop through the object, `push` the values to a new object, then `break` after `created_by` is reached.

```js
var arr = {1: "XX",
2: "XXXX",
3.2: "",
3.3: "XX",
3.4: "",
3.6: "X",
3.8: "",
4: "X",
5: "X",
8: "X",
10: "X",
11: "X",
12: "X",
13: "X",
created_by: "X",
test: 1
};

var newa = {};

for(i in arr){
  newa[i] = arr[i];
  if(i == "created_by"){
     break;
  }
}

console.log(newa);
```

Answer (score 0):

If that data is modelled as an object, it seems so from the keys, you do not have a definite chance to know in which order the keys are since JavaScript objects does not guarantee the order, unlike arrays.

If it is in your hands to retrieve this data as an array you could have the order guaranteed, and I would suggest you accordingly. Similar to the following hypothetical case's way.

You can an algorithm that accepts the names of the props value of which you want to render or not to render.

First, you need a filter algorithm for objects like that:

```
function filterObject(object, filteringFunction, initialAccumulator = {}) {
    return Object.entries(object)
        .filter(([key, value], indexInEntriesArray, entriesArray) => filteringFunction(key, value, indexInEntriesArray, entriesArray))
        .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({ ...acc, [key]: value }), initialAccumulator);
}
```

Having that in hand you can filter the keys from an object based on a custom filtering function you defined. You can do the filtering according to anything you want based on key, value, index in entries array (returned form the `Object.entries` call).

After that you need to map your `resData` array itself with that function, performing the filtering props(s) of each object as you see fit:

```
const mappedResData = resData.map(item => filterObject(item, myFilteringFunc))
```

with your custom `filteringFunction` to filter each object inside the array. You can do anything here. Here I just eliminate the key(s) that you list.

```
const myFilteringFunc = (key, val, i, entArr) => undesiredKeysArray.includes(key) === false;
```

where `undesiredKeysArray` is just an array of strings each of which is a property's name in each object in `resData`.

If order in JavaScript objects were guaranteed, which is not the case, you could `Object` static methods `keys`, `values` or `entries` to get and array of those and look for the name of the key you want to stop rendering at and `slice` that array at there, and render the return of that `slice` call.